# How to install jave EE ide for web developer on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I've been wondering how am I supposed to get Eclipse Java EE IDE for web developer.

I installed Neon Eclipse a month ago to do my core Java course and I'm starting on my Servlets and JSPs: Creating Web Application.

But I am unsure on how in doing it. My current neon eclipse only enable me to choose this option as shown below.

[image: demo]

Based on my online tutorial courses, I need to get this information when creating a file from eclipse. But my neon eclipse doesn't have the option that allows me to.

Do I need to download a new eclipse specially for Java EE IDE web developer? If yes, which should I be downloading? E.g luma or etc etc. Will it overwrite my current eclipse program that I have on my computer for my core Java? I am afraid that my current eclipse program will get affected.

Thanks in advance. Sorry, I'm new and unfamiliar with the software and how in doing it.

[image: demo]

Comment: Welcome at SO -  we respect the honest message your username tells. Friendly advice: take your time to do some tutorials, and even explore your tools yourself, and you'll be able to answer a lot of your questions. It is sadly not possible to skip this step - these will be the wrenches you'll work with, probably through quite some years... Check where the files of the IDE are, where the source files are stored, and follow advice you find in tutorials: you'll gain a lot of self confidence that'll come in handy in the professional life. (BTW Idea is a really good IDE)

Comment: @duffymo: there are those distinction with Intellij too. Some web features are not in the community edition. Please avoud polluting discussions with irrelevant and wrong statements.

Comment: @duffymo Is there a reason you keep wandering into Eclipse questions and  proselytizing IntelliJ?

Comment: I have a paid license; no distinction for me.  I've been an enthusiastic customer for 12 years.  I get tired of seeing Eclipse users suffering needlessly with an inferior product.  I am not a JetBrains employee; I get no sales cut if anyone adapts their product.

Comment: The wizards you're looking for might be under the `Other...` section. If not, try https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-ee-developer-tools-0 .

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse IDE is extensible or modular. If you didn't get the Java EE version initially, you can simply install into your existing IDE the support for Java EE. To do so, go to Help > Install Software... , on the installation dialog, show the Neon repository and find ymthe various extensions related to Java EE and Web development. Select them and click install. Upon restart, you'll get the Java EE support there.

Comment: They might be easier to find in the marketplace entry: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-ee-developer-tools-0 .